# UITableView with SKSTableViewCell Selection issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm using a [SKSTableView](https://github.com/sakkaras/SKSTableView) and everything is working fine. I'm encountering an issue and can't find a way for it.

When I expand the first and second cell and then select from the first expanded sub row cell, I get the second row name with the first selected sub row name. What I should get is the first name with first sub row name instead. How I can fix this issue?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  SKSTableViewCell *cell = (SKSTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self tableView:_tableView cellForSubRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  _selectedCellTxt = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

  if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(isExpandable)]){

      if ([cell isExpandable])
      {
          NSLog(@"SELECTED Row %@", _selectedCellTxt);
      }

  else{
         _selectedCellTxt = selectedCell.textLabel.text
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"123" sender:self];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(SKSTableView *)tableView didSelectSubRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self tableView:_tableView cellForSubRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  _selectedSubCellTxt = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
  NSLog(@"SELECTED Sub Row %@", _selectedSubCellTxt);

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"123" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: @gabbler Sorry what do you mean?

Comment: I always got the desired result when selecting the cells. Can't reproduce:"I get the second row name with the first selected sub row name."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I solve my issue by calling the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the `didSelectSubRowAtIndexPath`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    SKSTableViewCell *cell = (SKSTableViewCell *)[self tableView:_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self tableView:_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    _selectedCellTxt = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
}

- (void)tableView:(SKSTableView *)tableView didSelectSubRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  UITableViewCell *selectedSubCell = [self tableView:_tableView cellForSubRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  _selectedSubCellTxt = selectedSubCell.textLabel.text;

  UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self tableView:_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  _selectedCellTxt = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"123" sender:self];
}
```